# Group SQL by newly defined parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

i have gotten the task of creating a statistic from tables that look like this:

```
 Faculty
    1 FacultyName1
    2 FacultyName2
    3 FacultyName3
    4 FacultyName4
    5 FacultyName5
```

and this:

```
Student
1 StudentName1 FacultyNr2
2 StudentName2 FacultyNr3
3 StudentName3 FacultyNr5
4 StudentName4 FacultyNr2
```

now i have to create a statistic which Groups the Faculties into newly created fields and groups by them.

Say:

```
Faculty Group 1 Count: 3
Faculty Group 2 Count: 1
```

for this example lets say that all those of **FacultyName1,FacultyName2,FacultyName3** should be listet as of "Faculty Group 1" and **FacultyName4 and FacultyName5** as of "Faculty Group 2".

I started by doing the following:

```
Select Count(*)
FROM Student INNER JOIN Faculty on Student.FacultyID = Faculty.ID
```

But am stuck trying to understand how to Group, how i could create Groups in the Code, where i could just say: `Group by FacultyGroups (Select Case When FacultyName = 'FacultyName1' = 'Faculty Group 1')`
or something similiar, does anybody have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways, but this should work:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN f.Name IN ('FacultyName1', 'FacultyName2', 'FacultyName3') THEN 'FacultyGroup1'
        WHEN f.Name IN ('FacultyName4', 'FacultyName5') THEN 'FacultyGroup2'
    END AS FacultyGroup,
    COUNT(*) AS Students
FROM 
    Student s
    INNER JOIN Faculty f ON s.FacultyID = f.ID
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN f.Name IN ('FacultyName1', 'FacultyName2', 'FacultyName3') THEN 'FacultyGroup1'
        WHEN f.Name IN ('FacultyName4', 'FacultyName5') THEN 'FacultyGroup2'
    END;
```

If your "group" logic becomes too long then it will look messy in your query, so you might want to pre-calculate this.  You could do this by using a sub-query for example, so one part of your query (the sub query) would convert faculties to groups and the other "main" part would count the students per group.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have added a GroupID column in your Faculty table

```
SELECT COUNT(*), f.GroupID
FROM Student AS s
INNER JOIN Faculty AS f ON s.FacultyID = f.ID
GROUP BY f.GroupID
```

It gives you the number of student per group of faculties and the id of this group

Comment: No. The Groups have Totally new Names, not to be found on the DB